# Hibernate column name

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I don't know why Hibernate DDL (hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update) generate a table with this column names for the class below.

Table : BLC_CATEGORY_MEDIA_MAP

'**BLC_CATEGORY_CATEGORY_ID**', 'bigint(20)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, ''

'MEDIA_ID', 'bigint(20)', 'NO', 'MUL', NULL, ''

'**MAP_KEY**', 'varchar(255)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, ''

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BLC_CATEGORY_MEDIA_MAP")
public class CategoryMediaMap implements Serializable {
    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    CategoryMediaMapPK categoryMediaMapPK;

    **@Column(name = "KEY", nullable = false)**
    private String key;

    //get and set

    public static class CategoryMediaMapPK implements Serializable {
        /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        **@Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID", nullable = false)**
        private Long categoryId;

        @Column(name = "MEDIA_ID", nullable = false)
        private Long mediaId;

        // get and set
```

I didn't found any custom implementation of NamingStrategy, so.... why is this happening?